# Python: The object is not added to self

Tags: python, pytest

I create objects and want to add them to self, but for some reason they are not passed to it. How to do it correctly?

Attach the code and screenshot from debug

[Screenshot from debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySRK5.png)

````
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup_from_checklist")
class TestTags:

    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def page_builder(self, browser):
        self.checklist_tags = GeneralChecklistsTags(browser)
        self.checklist_index = GeneralChecklistIndex(browser)
        return self

    def test_to_go_dashboard(self, page_builder):
        a = 1
        page_builder.checklist_index.move_to_tags()
        h1 = page_builder.checklist_tags.get_title_h1()
        assert matcher.has_text(h1, 'General Checklists Tags') ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Split fixture into two and return one value at once.

```py
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup_from_checklist")
class TestTags:

    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def checklist_tags(self, browser):
        checklist_tags = GeneralChecklistsTags(browser)
        yield checklist_tags

    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def checklist_index(self, browser):
        checklist_index = GeneralChecklistIndex(browser)
        yield checklist_index

    def test_to_go_dashboard(self, checklist_tags, checklist_index):
        a = 1
        checklist_index.move_to_tags()
        h1 = checklist_tags.get_title_h1()
        assert matcher.has_text(h1, 'General Checklists Tags')
```

It's recommended to use "yield" instead of "return" in fixture.

Comment: Thank you, but I just don't want to do a lot of fixtures.
I want to put all the objects in "self" and use them via the "self"call

Example:
``` @pytest.mark.usefixtures("move_to_tags")
class TestTags:

    @pytest.fixture(scope="class")
    def page_builder(self, browser):
        self.checklist_tags = GeneralChecklistsTags(browser)
        self.checklist_index = GeneralChecklistIndex(browser)
        yield self

    def test_to_go_dashboard(self, page_builder):
        self.checklist_tags.get_title_h1() ``` 

How can this be done?